# What's the benefit of factory constructor in MapEntry class?

Tags: dart

Original code for [`MapEntry`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Map-class.html)

```dart
class MapEntry<K, V> {
  final K key;
  final V value;

  const factory MapEntry(K key, V value) = MapEntry<K, V>._;

  const MapEntry._(this.key, this.value);
}
```

What's the need to create above `factory` constructor when you can simply have:

```dart
class MapEntry<K, V> {
  final K key;
  final V value;

  const MapEntry(this.key, this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the constructor like this effectively makes the class final (Classes are unable to extend from this class). Only generative constructors can be used to call `super()`. This is as opposed to factory constructors which cannot be used in such a way. As the only generative constructor is the private one named `_`, extension is prevented. There is the caveat that classes in the same package could extend the class as private members are available to classes in the same package.

By having the factory constructor, instances of `MapEntry` can still be created even though the default constructor is private.

```
class MapEntry<K, V> {
  final K key;
  final V value;
  const factory MapEntry(K key, V value) = MapEntry<K, V>._;
  const MapEntry._(this.key, this.value);
  
}

class ExtendableMapEntry<K, V> {
  final K key;
  final V value;
  const ExtendableMapEntry(this.key, this.value);  
}


// ---------------

class GoodChild extends ExtendableMapEntry<int, int>{
  GoodChild(int i):super(i,i);
}

// Error:
// The constructor 'MapEntry<int, int> MapEntry(int key, int value)' is a
// factory constructor, but must be a generative constructor to be a valid
// superinitializer - line 24
class ImpossibleChild extends MapEntry<int, int>{
  ImpossibleChild(int i):super(i,i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Although I didn't get your `Only generative constructors can be used to call super()`. Even if I have a factory constructor in my subclass, I'm unable to call `super` in it.

Comment: That comment is not in reference to how to call the super in the child class, but rather which constructors in the parent class can be called. You cannot use a factory constructor to instantiate a super class. It is not allowed as it is possible a for a factory constructor to return a number of things that are not a new instance of that class (a pre-existing instance like a singleton, or an instance of a child class)

Comment: Yes, that explains. So, basically we can't use `super` to call parent's factory constructor in the subclass.